# Center multirow text and place it on each page in longtabu when page breaks

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, longtabu

So, the question is: **is it somehow possible?**

I need to use long table of some sort (I use longtabu), multirow of 9 rows, some rows contain parboxes.

When pagebreak occurs in the middle of multirow I want multirows's text appear on both pages (before and after pagebreak) vertically centered according to it's rows:

[image: This is what i wanna get]

Sorry for cyrillic letters.

It seems that the finest trick for vertical centering text in `multirows` is using invisible lines (like using `\cline{3-9}` instead of `\hline)` but this would spoil all the automation of tex and doesn't look properly.

---

EDITED: Here is sample code, took it from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201331/multirow-not-working-with-long-tabu) (it's close). You can see that `\multirow` doesn't work properly with page break.
Once again with sample code:

1. Can I make `\multirow` work with pagebreak? Do I have to use some other command/package for making a multirow?
2. Is there an opportunity to make `\multirow`'s text appear on both pages: before and after pagebreak?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package Inclusions %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%used to print Spanish characters in the text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Configurations   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\geometry{
      top=0.50in,            
      inner=0.75in,
      outer=0.75in,
      bottom=0.50in,
      headheight=3ex,      
      headsep=6ex,          
    }

\setlength{\LTpre}{1pt} % removes the white space before a long table
\setlength{\LTpost}{1pt} % removes the white space after a long table
\pagestyle{empty} % stops the page number from showing on each page
\tabulinesep=1mm


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start Report       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\Large
{\textbf{Test Report}}
\small

\begin{longtabu} to 9.5in {
    |X[1.5,l,m]|
    X[4,l,m]|
    X[2.5,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[3,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[8,l,m]|
    }
    \hline

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Customer Name:}} &
    \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\textbf{Well Name:}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Job Date:}}

    \\

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{test} &
    \multicolumn{5}{l|}{test well} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{22/08/2014}


    \\\hline

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Customer Representative:}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{County/Parish:}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{State:}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Job Category:}}

    \\\cline{5-9}

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Health} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{test} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Texas} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Wash Fill/Sand Removal} \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Time}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Activity Name}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}{\centering\textbf{Tubing Depth}}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering\textbf{Pressure}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm} {\centering\textbf{Tubing Weight}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}
{\centering\textbf{Liquid Rate}}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering\textbf{Flow black Rate / Liquid Type}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}{\centering\textbf{N2 Rate}}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Activity Info}}} \\\cline{4-5}
    & & & 
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Circulation} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Wellhead} &
    & & & & \\\cline{3-9}
    & &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Start/End} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(psi)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(psi)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(lbs)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(bbl/min)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(bbl)/Name} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(SCF/min)} & 
\\\hline %cline{3-9}
 \endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Continued on next page ...} \\ 
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot
    & & & & & & & & &\\\hline
\end{longtabu}



\begin{longtabu} to 9.88 in {
    |X[1.5,l,m]|
    X[4,l,m]|
}
\hline   
\multirow{9}{*}{test1} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{9}{*}{test2} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{9}{*}{test3} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{19}{*}{test4} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{2-2}
&10 \\ \cline{2-2}
&11 \\ \cline{2-2}
&12 \\ \cline{2-2}
&13 \\ \cline{2-2}
&14 \\ \cline{1-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{2-2}
\hline   
\end{longtabu}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I dont have access to this file right now, i'll upload it on monday. I'll tag you here when it's ready

Comment: I don't know if I can help you, but with a mwe I'm sure someone will.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Hey check it out

Answer (score 1):

If David Carisle didn't find a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267811/101651), I doubt there is one...

If you don't want to adjust it manually (that is, when your document is almost finished, divide the block of multirow in two little ones, in order to have one of them in the first page and the other in the second), I suggest putting the entire block of multirow automatically on the second page.

From the `multirow` package documentation, Section 3.6 Use with longtable:

> ... omissis ... you want to prevent the pagebreak to occur in the
>   middle of this entry. You can do this by ending the intermediate rows
>   with `\\*` instead of `\\`.
>
> ... omissis ...  There is, however, a bug in `longtable`, that causes the `\\*` not to work if it is followed by a `\cline`
>
> ... omissis ... `multirow` has a package option `longtable` that
>   redefines `\cline` so that the `\\*` will also work when followed by
>   `\cline`. The code comes from David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Package Inclusions %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%used to print Spanish characters in the text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Configurations   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\geometry{
      top=0.50in,            
      inner=0.75in,
      outer=0.75in,
      bottom=0.50in,
      headheight=3ex,      
      headsep=6ex,          
    }

\setlength{\LTpre}{1pt} % removes the white space before a long table
\setlength{\LTpost}{1pt} % removes the white space after a long table
\pagestyle{empty} % stops the page number from showing on each page
\tabulinesep=1mm


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start Report       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\Large
{\textbf{Test Report}}
\small

\begin{longtabu} to 9.5in {
    |X[1.5,l,m]|
    X[4,l,m]|
    X[2.5,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[3,l,m]|
    X[2,l,m]|
    X[8,l,m]|
    }
    \hline

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Customer Name:}} &
    \multicolumn{5}{l|}{\textbf{Well Name:}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Job Date:}}

    \\

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{test} &
    \multicolumn{5}{l|}{test well} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{22/08/2014}


    \\\hline

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Customer Representative:}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{County/Parish:}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{State:}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Job Category:}}

    \\\cline{5-9}

    \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Health} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{test} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Texas} &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Wash Fill/Sand Removal} \\ \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Time}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|} {\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Activity Name}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}{\centering\textbf{Tubing Depth}}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\centering\textbf{Pressure}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm} {\centering\textbf{Tubing Weight}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}
{\centering\textbf{Liquid Rate}}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{3cm}{\centering\textbf{Flow black Rate / Liquid Type}}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{1cm}{\centering\textbf{N2 Rate}}}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\centering\textbf{Activity Info}}} \\\cline{4-5}
    & & & 
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Circulation} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Wellhead} &
    & & & & \\\cline{3-9}
    & &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{Start/End} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(psi)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(psi)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(lbs)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(bbl/min)} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(bbl)/Name} &
    \centering\scriptsize\textbf{(SCF/min)} & 
\\\hline %cline{3-9}
 \endhead
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{Continued on next page\ldots} \\ 
 \endfoot
 \endlastfoot
 & & & & & & & & &\\\hline
\end{longtabu}


\begin{longtabu} to 9.88 in {
    |X[1.5,l,m]|
    X[4,l,m]|
}
\hline   
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Continued on next page\ldots} \\ 
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\multirow{9}{*}{test1} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{9}{*}{test2} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{9}{*}{test3} 
&1 \\ \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\ \cline{2-2}
&3 \\ \cline{2-2}
&4 \\ \cline{2-2}
&5 \\ \cline{2-2}
&6 \\ \cline{2-2}
&7 \\ \cline{2-2}
&8 \\ \cline{2-2}
&9 \\ \cline{1-2}
\hline   
\multirow{19}{*}{test4} 
&1 \\* \cline{2-2}    
&2 \\* \cline{2-2}
&3 \\* \cline{2-2}
&4 \\* \cline{2-2}
&5 \\* \cline{2-2}
&6 \\* \cline{2-2}
&7 \\* \cline{2-2}
&8 \\* \cline{2-2}
&9 \\* \cline{2-2}
&10 \\* \cline{2-2}
&11 \\* \cline{2-2}
&12 \\* \cline{2-2}
&13 \\* \cline{2-2}
&14 \\* \cline{2-2}
&15 \\* \cline{2-2}
&16 \\* \cline{2-2}
&17 \\* \cline{2-2}
&18 \\* \cline{2-2}
&19 \\* \cline{2-2}
\hline   
\end{longtabu}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

First page:

[image]

Second page:

[image]

Comment: it seems that OP forgot on your answer :-(

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your upvote... Unfortunately it happens sometimes :):):)